# C++ templates pointer-to-reference-type tomfoolery

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, reference

I have the following struct static method:

```
template<typename Edge1, typename Edge2, typename... Edges>
requires std::derived_from<Edge1, Edge> && std::derived_from<Edge2, Edge> && (std::derived_from<Edges, Edge> && ...)
[[nodiscard]] static constexpr bool are_multi_edges(const Edge1& edge1, const Edge2& edge2, const Edges&... edges)
{
    // If only two edges were passed to the function, there's no need for any extra logic.
    if constexpr (sizeof...(edges) == 0)
        return edge1 == edge2;

    // Problem here //
    std::array<Edge, sizeof...(edges) + 1> array {edge2, edges...};
    // Problem here //

    for (auto& [from, to] : array)
        if (from != edge1.from || to != edge1.to)
            return false;
        
    return true;
}// with "Edge" being the name of the actual struct housing the static method.
```

Emphasis on std::array<***Edge***, ....... > .......

If I leave the "Edge" as-is, the code compiles and works fine, but I suspect it copies `edge2` and `edges` into the array, which is unnecessary. I tried replacing "Edge" with "Edge&" to avoid copies and got the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/10/array: In instantiation of ‘struct std::array<Edge<>&, 1>’:

/home/selamba/CLionProjects/graphs_lol/graph.h:41:43: required from ‘static constexpr bool Edge<VertexType>::are_multi_edges(const Edge1&, const Edge2&, const Edges& ...) [with Edge1 = Edge<>; Edge2 = Edge<>; Edges = {}; VertexType = char]’


/home/selamba/CLionProjects/graphs_lol/main.cpp:13:51:   required from here


/usr/include/c++/10/array:97:35: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘std::array<Edge<>&, 1>::value_type’ {aka ‘Edge<>&’}


   97 |       typedef value_type*         pointer;


      |                                   ^~~~~~~
```

With the main takeaway being "forming pointer to reference type". This is only the top part of the error message as the actual message is enormous. All the errors are actually in the "array" header file (usr/include/c++/10/array).

Is it possible to form a std::array of Edge references in my use case? If so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std reference wrappers.  References are not regular, and are unsuitable for use in std containers.

Reference wrappers are half way between a reference and a pointer, but are regular enough to be container contents.

Comment: Thank you
6 more symbols required to post comment